# What would be a practical implementation of the Azure enterprise-scale landing zone architecture?

Tags: azure, architecture

I've been reading through the [Microsoft Cloud Adoption Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/enterprise-scale/architecture) for some time now. In our company, we have a similar implementation (hub-spoke), but a lot less modular like it is depicted in the docs. We don't have an identity or management subscription for example.

When looking at our own hub-spoke architecture, we basically only have 2 spokes: non-prod and prod in which we deploy all applications (VMs) inside one big VNet (one per spoke). Since we have hundreds of VMs ranging from very small tools on a single VM up to large complex setups with dozens of VMs, we would eventually also have many landing zones (and therefor VNets) I suppose? Our hub contains central shared services like the firewall, domain controllers etc.

Important to know is that we don't do any in-house application development or let other departments like marketing deploy Azure resources themselves. We basically setup Azure infrastructure into the spokes from within our central IT infrastructure department and give external partners access to deploy their applications into it.

What I'm particularly curious about is when you would decide to create a new landing zone in this architecture? Would you have a landing zone for each application? One for each department to enable self-service? Is our approach a good idea?

Very interested to learn how other companies are implementing this architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The big part of enterprise scale landing zone is probably the modules you mentioned that are missing in your implementation.(Or any start small type of land zone)

1. Enroll in EA so you have an account to manage multiple subscriptions
2. Have the proper resource organization in place(management groups and
   subscriptions).This ensures that you can deploy policies and RBAC
   etc at the proper level.

Landing Zone sits on much high level than the applications(resource groups). There is no need for more than 1 Landing Zone. You maybe need to extended it, by either creating new Spoke, and/or in some case new subscription.